# pandas merge method issue

Tags: python, pandas

I have tried to use the merge method in the pandas and checked the documentation in the official website.

```
df_new = df.merge(data1, data2, on="Store", how="inner")
```

When trying to run this method, I keep getting the following error.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [26], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 df_new = df.merge(data1, data2, on="Store", how="inner")

TypeError: merge() got multiple values for argument 'how'
```

Note that `data1` and `data2` are both imported with `pd.readcsv()` method. I've checked multiple sources but still seems not helpful to me at all. Any contribution would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also note: I've tried to use `[data1, data2]`, in the `merge` method too. but still doesn't seems to be working out. thank you guys!

Comment: The syntax is `pd.merge(left_dataframe,right_dataframe,how='left',on='<common_column>')`
You are using df instead of pd

Answer (score 1):

kindly try merging using any unique value column like 'ID', and try pd.merge

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).